# create table with system date in Vertica

Tags: sql, vertica

I am looking to create table from a table something like:

```
CREATE TABLE as archive.POSTPAID_GSMIS_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S` 
(
select * from 
POSTPAID.STAGE_GS10);
commit;
```

Wondering if I can even do it in Vertica?

I thought of storing value in a variable like:

```
\set x 'select now();'

create table :x (int a);
```

But `\echo :x` gives me `select now();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the code bellow

```
dbadmin=> \set date `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`

dbadmin=> \echo :date
20170815112242
 CREATE TABLE dba.POSTPAID_GSMIS_:date
 as
select '1234' as id from dual
;
CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> select * from dba.POSTPAID_GSMIS_:date;
  id
------
 1234
(1 row)
```

- is this what you are looking for ?

**Append Unix timestamp to a tablename:**

```
dbadmin=> \set env `date +%s`
dbadmin=> \echo :env
1502843933

dbadmin=> create table dba.tbl_:env (id int);
CREATE TABLE

dbadmin=> select * from dba.tbl_1502843933;
 id
----
(0 rows)
```

**Also you can build you variable and use it on table create**

```
dbadmin=> \set var `var="blabla" && echo $var`
dbadmin=> \echo :var
blabla
dbadmin=>  create table dba.tbl_:var (id int);
CREATE TABLE
dbadmin=> select * from dba.tbl_blabla;
 id
----
(0 rows)
```

Comment: I am looking to export system time and use the same system time when I create a table. Can i do this: \set date `$var` where var is environment variable storing system date? I tried this but doesn't work.

Comment: So you want to create table based on "external" var value ?